exit from running, sourcing, or pasting a series of commands in bash
I'm writing a script that I run directly, "source" from the bash console, or cut/paste as a sequence of commands into a console from an editor window.  The script or its pasted commands may encounter an error and need to exit; when it does, I do not want to exit the console.
The problem is pasting commands into the terminal because each line is treated independently: aborting on one line will still execute the subsequent lines.  I do not want to rely on external commands, only Bash.
I have come up with a way to do this, but am wondering if there's an easier/better way.  Put this into a script then either run it, source, it, or paste the commands into a console window:
#!/bin/bash
# test of exit from running, sourcing, or pasting a series of commands

# return fails implies either running or pasting; if not running, then pasting
shopt -s expand_aliases
SAVEOPTS=/tmp/$$.bashopts
saveopts () {
    set | egrep -v '(BASHOPTS|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID)=' >$SAVEOPTS
    alias >>$SAVEOPTS
}
alias EXIT="{ echo 'exit required, terminating' ; \
    return 2 >&/dev/null || \
    [[ '${0}' == '${BASH_SOURCE[0]}' ]] && exit 2; \
    saveopts ; exec bash --rcfile $SAVEOPTS; }" 

# usage
echo "good stuff"           # commands that should pass
true || EXIT                # example of a successful command
echo "more good stuff"      # another good command
false || EXIT               # failed command
echo "SHOULD NOT SEE THIS"  # do not want this to run

I'm using this in GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1).
How it works - call EXIT when you wish to terminate.

If sourcing the script, e.g., source 1.sh, the return 2 in the alias causes the sourcing to stop.

If running the script directly, e.g., bash 1.sh or just ./1.sh, the return 2 fails and falls through to the second condition that checks whether the name of the process is the name of the script. This succeeds, resulting in an exit 2.

If pasting, these first two conditions don't take effect, so instead it re-execs the current shell bringing back in the previous settings.  Using exec preserves the PID of the shell.  (The grep -v's are for unsettable options and is done to prevent the shell from trying to set these.)


This generally feels fragile.  Is there a better way?
I'd like to have EXIT as the command, but am open to eval something, or a function call, or something else, as long as it's relatively short.  I also prefer not to depend on external commands (which I don't have installed) such as xclip.
Revisions to this post:

Added the exec logic simplifying the entire thing
This is a different question than another question having to do with aliases and not terminating a list of pasted commands.


Related: set -e

"The problem is pasting commands into the terminal because each line is treated independently" ... you don't have bracketed paste enabled yet?

How would bracketed paste be used in this context?

A multiline block is pasted in together: https://i.sstatic.net/QSkVKMln.pngNow all you need to do is wrap the thing in { ...; }: https://i.sstatic.net/KnStNfnG.png, and the entire block gets cancelled at once. This wouldn't work if bracketed paste is disabled and each line gets treated as if its input individually.

Not clear how you make use of this when pasting.  { good command; failed command || <what goes here?> ; dont_run_this_if_failed; }

I would suggest the solution is to stop pasting multiline commands like that. If you're doing that more than twice with the same script, you should instead put it in a separate file or a function.

Seems reasonable.  I'll leave this open to see if I get other answers.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Your current alias with just the first two cases - without the broken heredoc - should work in that code. But to second @ilkkachu, when I need to paste complex stuff into a shell, I use Ctrl-x Ctrl-e to get an editor, paste into that and adjust as needed for whatever I am actually doing

Found a way that does not abuse the heredoc feature.

I feel like your EXIT command better be handled using a trap.

@FelixJN, I'm open to that! ;-)  Can you suggest what I would do?  Re-execing the shell is absolutely clunky.

@Russ That is a topic (and question) of its own. Have a read of man bash -> SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS -> trap. In general you define a command to be executed once the shell receives an exit call or a certain signal. trap <command(s)> SIGNAL(S). Usually, you define your EXIT (better as function called e.g. cleanup) in the beginning, then go trap cleanup EXIT. Note that  EXIT defines the closure conditions here, hence better avoid that name for your alias in the first place.

OK, but how do you trap out of a script that is being sourced? I don’t know if there is any built-in that says stop sourcing this script.

I believe the proper way is to use return.
